# PHP - Сессии и куки

Tags: php, wordpress, cookie, сессия, кэширование

Приветствую!

Я использую WordPress и сделал свою функцию определения мобильного устройства ( т.к. нужно более точечное действие ).

Логика такая - если человек, зашелс мобильного устройства - открывается мобильная версия и создается сессия. Далее есть кнопки полной версии и мобильной. Они попросту переключают значение сессии.

```
    function version_handler(){
if ( empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ) {
    $mob = FALSE;
} elseif ( strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Mobile') !== FALSE
    || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Android') !== FALSE
    || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Silk/') !== FALSE
    || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Kindle') !== FALSE
    || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'BlackBerry') !== FALSE
    || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera Mini') !== FALSE
    || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera Mobi') !== FALSE ) {

        if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad')){
            $mob = FALSE;
        }else{
            $mob = TRUE;
        }

} else {
    $mob = FALSE;
}
if(isset($_SESSION['is_mobile']) && $_SESSION['is_mobile'] === TRUE){
    return TRUE;
}elseif(isset($_SESSION['is_mobile']) && $_SESSION['is_mobile'] === FALSE){
    return FALSE;
}elseif(!isset($_SESSION['is_mobile'])){
    return $mob;
}}
```

Есть и "переключатель":

```
  if($_REQUEST['switch']){
$action = $_REQUEST['switch'];
if($action === 'mobile') {
    $_SESSION['is_mobile'] = true;
     header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/');
}elseif($action === 'full'){
    $_SESSION['is_mobile'] = FALSE;
    if ($_REQUEST['url']) {
        header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/'.$_REQUEST['url']);
    } elseif(!$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) {
        header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/');
    }else{
        header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }
}}
```

В связи с тем, что сайт испытывает серьезную нагрузку - врубаем кеширование. Теперь необходимо перевести `$_SESSION['mobile']` в куки. Я это сделал, и на десктопах работает отлично, но не на мобильных устройствах.

Вопрос: 
Как мне реализовать переход с `$_SESSION` на `$_COOKIE` или альтернативу, которая бы работала как на мобильных устройствах, так и на ПК?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Зачем переводить данные из сессии в куки? Сессии и так хранят свой идентификатор в куках. Или вы полностью от сессий в выше представленном коде хотите отказаться?

Comment: для кеширования. На самом деле я уже нашел решение. Дело было в проверке - `version_handler`. Если устройство было мобильным - функция честно про это сообщала) Словом нельзя писать код в 4 утра :)